# Solidity Smart Contract throws an Error "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address"

Tags: solidity, transfer

Here is the function that throws an error

```
function transferEther(address rec,uint _amount) public payable {
  address(rec).transfer(_amount);
    }
```

I get the following error:

TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address". address(rec).transfer(_amount); ^-------------------^

Comment: As said in the error message, your "rec" attribute must be of type address payable and not only address.
To make the conversion use this : `address(uint160(rec))`

Answer (score 0):

Variable `rec` is not `payable`, thus you can't transfer value. Here is the fixed version:

```
function transferEther(address payable rec, uint _amount) public payable {
    rec.transfer(_amount);
}
```